# add options to select using existing dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to populate dropdown2 from existing dropdown. I am targeting this dropdowns using its classes.

Also, want to add selected option from dropdown to dropdown2.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="dropdown" EnableViewState="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>

                <select class="dropdown2"></select>
```

Then, on change i have this :

```
$(".dropdown").change(function () {
    var selectedText = $(".dropdown option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(".dropdown option:selected").attr('value')

    $('.dropdown option').each(function () {

        $(".dropdown2").append(new Option($(this).text(), $(this).attr('value')));
    });

    $(".dropdown2 option:contains(" + selectedText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

How to populate select and add options using existing dropdownlist ??

Comment: It's not going to work since you have an asp.net dropdown list with postback. your js logic would never execute.

Comment: i need that dropdown with post back because i have repeater binding on changed selection ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with asp.net Dropdown list, you need to do some hack to make it work. Asp.net event would supersede any js events and would automatically trigger a postback.

**ASPX :**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="dropdown" EnableViewState="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
<select class="dropdown2"></select>
<script>
var valueChanged = '<%=ValueChanged%>'; // get the server side variable and assign its value to a js variable
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(valueChanged.toLowerCase() == 'true')
    {
    var selectedText = $(".dropdown option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(".dropdown option:selected").attr('value')

    $('.dropdown option').each(function () {
    $(".dropdown2").append("<option id="$(this).attr('value')">$(this).text()</option");
    });

    $(".dropdown2 option:contains(" + selectedText + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
   }
});

</script>
```

**ASPX.CS :**

```
public class Test
 {

   public bool ValueChanged = false;  // declare a public variable 
   protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   ValueChanged = true; // set the value to true on index change.
}

 }
```